# Using a dynamic priority dict or list to remove possible duplicate elements in a complex dict(keep it only for the biggest priority element/key)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a complex dict, with many elements, simplifying looks like this:

```
grouped = {
    "ca": {"k_a": 32, "k_d": 34},
    "ct": {"p_a": 98, "k_d": 34},
    "cd": {"k_a": 32, "c_a": 12},
}
```

and a list of valid keys:

```
valid = ["k_a", "k_d", "p_a"]
```

and the following code (simplified):

```
def process(v):
   .........
    return v


for kd, vd in grouped.items():
    for k, v in vd.items():
        if k in valid:
            new = dict(v)
            new.update({"channel": kd})
            processed.append(process(new))
```

Because some elements are repeated for multiple key/channels for example:
`k_a`is in "ca" and in "cd"
`k_d` is in "ca" and "ct"

a simple result for process will be like this:

```
[{'k_a': 32, channel': 'ca'}, {'k_a': 32, 'channel': 'ct'}, ...]
```

What I want is each element like `k_a` to appear only in one channel.
Also which channel to be used, first to be based on a priority dict or list. Example:

```
priority = {
    "ca": 3,
    "ct": 1,
}

or priority = ["ct", "ca"]

[{'k_a': 32, 'channel': 'ca'},......]
```

If it is not on the priority dict/list(based on index) will not have a priority the minimum one.

I can do that by creating 3 lists per the two priority keys and check one by one, something like this:

```
d_ca = {}
d_ct  = {}
d_rest = {}
  if k in d_a:
    # do nothing
  .....
```

but I want to be something dynamic to not create the dict manually, in case the priority list/dict change to not change the code that read the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a dictionary to hold your outputs, then convert to list:

```
S = set(valid) # use a set for efficiency

out = {}       # dictionary to hold our values per key

for kd, vd in grouped.items():
    for k, v in vd.items():
        if (k in S  # check that the key is valid
            and (not k in out or  # if this is a new key
                 # or if the existing one has lower priority
                 # (default priority is defined as 0)
                 priority.get(kd, 0)>priority.get(out[k]['channel'], 0))
            ):
            out[k] = {k: v, 'channel': kd} # then add/replace

# keep only the dictionary values   
processed = list(out.values())
```

Output:

```
[{'k_a': 32, 'channel': 'ca'},
 {'k_d': 34, 'channel': 'ca'},
 {'p_a': 98, 'channel': 'ct'}]
```

Used input:

```
grouped = {
    "ca": {"k_a": 32, "k_d": 34},
    "ct": {"p_a": 98, "k_d": 34},
    "cd": {"k_a": 32, "c_a": 12},
}

valid = ["k_a", "k_d", "p_a"]

priority = {
    "ca": 3,
    "ct": 1,
}
```